# Vanished/truncated discussion. What happened?

Tags: discussion, comment

On question [2249994](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2249994), there was a lively discussion about whether use of the construct either/or meant (1.) inclusive-or or (2.) exclusive-or. Today I revisited it and found that the bulk of the discussion, in which I had taken a tiny part, seems to have vanished. Wha' hoppen?

Comment: When the length of a comment exchange exceeds a certain threshold an automatic flag is raised by the system. This summons a diamond moderator to the scene. We mentally then run our algorithm (probably varies from one mod to the other a little, but not significantly), and delete the whole lot, if we judge that to be prudent. Personally I will take into account things such as whether the discussion is still going on at full steam (when I leave the flag open and revisit it later and/or let a colleague make the decision).

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen \ I suppose a question should have been directed to the OP as to what meaning her use of "either/or" was intended to convey. Thanks, Dr. Lahtonen.